# pascal string to date

Tags: date, pascal, freepascal

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this piece of code:

```
ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
j:=StrToDate('05/05/1999');
```

I keep getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $000000000042FA33 :
EConvertError : Invalid date format
```

I'm using fpc.

Comment: Is your DateSeparator global variable set to '/'?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the default value was '-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this in your code before the `StrToDate` call:

> `Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Date));`

If the output does not contain `/` but another character, you must use this character as separator in your string.

On my system this gives: `11.11.2009`. If I then use `05.05.1999`it does work.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/fpc-pascal@lists.freepascal.org/msg17937.html) (paraphrased):

> *StrToDate* does not use *ShortDateFormat* to check the actual format; it uses it only to determine the order of *y,m,d* and then uses *DateSeparator* to determine the actual date separator character.

So what you need is:

```
ShortDateFormat := 'd/m/y';
DateSeparator := '/';
j:=StrToDate('05/05/1999');
```

You may want to think about either:

- saving `ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator` before doing this so you can restore them (they're set initially based on your locale); or
- using dates based on your actual settings, and not change those two values at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide ordering and separator as arguments without modifying the globals:

```
j := StrToDate('05/05/1999', 'd/m/y', '/');
```